# How to automate the process to update all dates at once in multiple SQL queries in Teradata

Tags: sql, macros, teradata

I'm doing monthly reporting and I have a couple of SQL codes ready to pull data.

I have following codes:

```sql
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE NEW_CUSTOMER IN 'YES'
AND Date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-07'

SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-07'
```

Every week I run these codes, I have to manually update the dates in the WHERE Statement. Is there a way (for example using Macro) to update the dates only once and click a button or something to get all dates in these codes updated?

I tried to use MACRO but didn't work. Maybe what I wrote was wrong.

```sql
CREATE MACRO Get_daily (DATE date) AS (
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE NEW_CUSTOMER IN 'YES'
AND Date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-07'

SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-07');
```

Comment: *monthly reporting*, are there rules to determine the date range, e.g. full current month or 1. to 7. or first week? Most clients including Teradata Studio support parameters/place holders: `where datecol between ?\startdate and ?\enddate` When you press F5 there's a prompt, uncheck the NULL and type in the date

Answer (score 0):

Using `current_date` and `interval` functions you can create a rule based on the current date you're running the query. You didn't make clear your criteria for selecting dates, but assuming you want to select the new customers from the past week, it would become something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE NEW_CUSTOMER IN 'YES'
AND Date BETWEEN current_date AND current_date - interval '6' day
```

Comment: Also if you must use Date as column name, please make it a quoted identifier `"Date"` since DATE is a reserved word (in multiple contexts).